# Confused about doing ajax call with ActionLink inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a partial view:

```
foreach (var documentFolder in Model.DocumentFolders){
    <span id="Folder">
        @Html.ActionLink(documentFolder.DisplayNameProperty, "ControllerAction", "Controller", null, new{@name = documentFolder.IDProperty, @id = "lbGetFile", @class = "textLink", @style = "text-decoration: underline; color: blue; cursor: pointer;"})
    </span>
}
```

I have this jquery code:

```
$("#lbGetFile").click(function (){
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: "POST",
            data: { selectedFolderID: $("#lbGetFile").attr('name') },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

What I'm noticing is that only the first item from my for loop works correctly in regards to returning the success function. Its probably because every item in the for loop has the same id, but I cant figure out what to do otherwise?

Also, I would think instead of a for loop an Editor Template should work better here, but can a successful ajax call correctly rewrite an editor template area?

Comment: This is because of the same ID indeed. However you can easily get rid of it completely. Just pick a different selector, say by class and element, and use `this` inside the handler

Comment: @andrei, So... how do you write a JQuery selector when one is dynamic?  I can understand selecting a tag based on say "id='hello' class='world'" using $("#hello .world").

Comment: Expanded in an answer. Hopefully it will clarify this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is indeed due to the same id. Not only that - all your `span` tags has the same id `Folder` as well. It might be a good idea to revisit this completely and remove ids from the code at all. So the markup would be something like that:

```
foreach (var documentFolder in Model.DocumentFolders){
    <span class="folder">
        @Html.ActionLink(documentFolder.DisplayNameProperty, "ControllerAction", "Controller", null, new{@name = documentFolder.IDProperty, @class = "textLink", @style = "text-decoration: underline; color: blue; cursor: pointer;"})
    </span>
}
```

Note that there are no IDs anymore, classes instead. Classes allow repetition easily and cause no conflicts.

As for javascript - here is how you do querying:

```
$("span.folder .textLink").click(function (){
```

This will select all the links you need. And you already know that you can use `this` inside the handler to reference currently clicked element.

Comment: Thx @Andrei, this worked great.  For anyone that was confused like me to select this structure `<span id="Folder"><span class="textLink"><a class="textLink">` in JQuery goes `$("#Folder .textLink .textLink").click(function(){`